# Special characters like "Å, Ä , Ö" ruin the displayed text in my twitter share javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, razor

I have a javascript that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#share_buttont@(number)').click(function () {
            var url = 'http://twitter.com/share?url=' + '&text=' + "@item.Title. News via www.newsifi.com" + '&';
            window.open(decodeURIComponent(url2), 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 225) + ', left=' + $(window).width() / 2 + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I debug the url variable the data looks like this:

```
http://twitter.com/share?url=undefined&text=&#197;rsb&#228;sta av Bengtsson – tog EM-brons. News via www.url.com&"
```

`@item.Title` have this data:

> Årsbästa av Bengtsson – tog EM-brons

It seems like special characters like "Å, Ä and Ö and etc" get weird format. When URL is returned it is blank or it gets cut when a special format is in place.

I have tried using encode and decode but it seems to not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#share_buttont@(number)').click(function () {
            var url = 'http://twitter.com/share?url=' + '&text=' + "@item.Title. News via www.newsifi.com" + '&';
            window.open(decodeURIComponent(url2), 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 225) + ', left=' + $(window).width() / 2 + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
        });
    });
</script>
```

also tried to `encodeURICompontent()`

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use server side encode, I assume you're using C#

```
var url = 'http://twitter.com/share?url=' + '&text=' + "@Server.UrlEncode(item.Title) ...";
```

Comment: I will try that its a .cshtml file yeah asp.net mvc